# How are machine learning models updated?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How are machine learning models updated in web apps?

Take SKLearn for example, after training a huge model (let's say on 10gb of data) how might you update the model based on the current day's new data?

Presumably you wouldn't want to update real time, maybe something like once at the end of each day– but I can't find a way to do this in SKLearn. Do you just have to re-train the entire thing on the entire ever growing data set every day?

Comment: It would depend on how you designed your model (single classifier or ensamble) or maybe a neural network? If you have multiple classifiers and depending on the data you might not need to re-train the entire model, but only some parts of the model.

Comment: [Have a look at this last part of the video](https://youtu.be/qyvlt7kiQoI?t=1h3m23s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of estimators in sklearn implement `partial_fit` that allows incremental (online) learning. Check this [article](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html).